# Tkinter mouse motion handler high CPU use

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Treeview in which I change the headings based on whether the element below the mouse is a top level element or not. For this I use the `<Motion>` event:

What I noticed is, unless I use the `after` function to schedule the motion callback, it leads to CPU spikes. I also use a `deque` to make sure that at most, the callback is scheduled for once only. This means that if the `deque` will be popped and if it has an element, then only it will be cancelled and rescheduled again.

EDIT: I noticed that this happens only for a table where the number of items is significant (5000+)

```py
import collections
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Tv(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tv = ttk.Treeview()
        self.tv.bind("<Motion>", lambda *_: self.manage_headings())
        self.tv.pack()
        self._after_dq = collections.deque(1)

    def manage_headings():
        def after_func():
            if self.tv.parent(iid):
                pass
            else:
                pass
        try:
            prev_id = self._after_dq.popleft()
        except IndexError:
            self._after_dq.append(self.after(10, after_func))
        else:
            self.after_cancel(prev_id)
```

However I notice, the CPU usage doesn't really go down than from just using `after` directly and not even bothering to cancel it later.